# passing value from js controller to apxc controller

Tags: lightning

I am new here, and I am having some issues passing values from my js controller to my apex controller:

Here my js

```
getDate : function(component, event, helper){
    var sDate = component.find('startDateRent').get("v.value");
    var eDate = component.find('startDateRent').get("v.value");
    var action = component.get("c.getBikes");
    action.setParams({"d":sDate});
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

and here my apex controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Bike__c> getBikes(Datetime d) {
    return [
        system.debug(d);
            Select Id, Name, Title__c, Description__c, Hour_price__c, Image__c 
            From Bike__c
            WHERE Id IN (Select Bike_reference__c FROM Rent__c 
            where Start_date_time__c = : d )
           ];
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What are your issues, exactly?

Comment: You should probably start by moving the system.debug statement outside of the query brackets

Comment: I'm surprised it even compiles

Comment: Also, you might want to check the format of the `v.value` part - it needs to be in yyyy-MM-dd format to pass to the controller

Comment: Sorry, my debug is out of the brackets, my bad. What I want to do is just get the datetime value and use it in my controller. The value goes ok to the js controller, but in my apex controller it gives a null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not setting a callback in your action. Try the below:

```
var action = component.get("c.getBikes");
    //set parameters send to apex
    action.setParams({"d":sDate});

    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            callback(response.getReturnValue());
        } else {
            //handle error
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```